# No sound, printer, or wireless connections

Tags: wireless, sound, printing, canon, pixma

Had sound after installation but not now; Have not been able to connect to Canon Pixma iP2600; Have not been able to connect wirelessly.

Comment: Did everything work if use the live mode "Try Ubuntu"? How did you installed Ubuntu?

Comment: Consider editing your question to describe if you have done anything from when the sound worked to now.

Comment: Also consider splitting your sound difficulties apart from your printer issues as a separate question - that way, you can describe what steps you've already taken and it will keep the flow for both questions cleaner.